# Nvarchar (Multi Language) variable is not able to search using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, nvarchar

I have a stored procedure which contains @Parm parameter with Nvarchar data type which will search data from table XYZ which will store data of multi language data  (Nvarchar) like 'బుక్స్ లవర్స్ కి విజ్ఞప్తి' or 'समाचार  पत्र' etc.

Whenever I am trying to search using stored procedure by passing search values we not getting values.

The below is code snippet for procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].Searc_String @SearchParam nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Xyz WHERE columnsname LIKE N'%'+@SearchParam+'%'
END
```

And trying to call like below:

```
EXEC [dbo].Searc_String  @SearchParam = N'బుక్స్ లవర్స్ కి విజ్ఞప్తి'
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data for us to repro

Comment: You will have a problem with the Collation of Your database/table/column.
Since a column can only have one collation it is not possible to store arabic and latin characters alongside in one column afaik

Comment: How can resolve this problem ;i am able to get  data when i am passing adhoc query like 
select * from xyz where columnsname like N'%బుక్స్ లవర్స్ కి విజ్ఞప్తి%'   Please suggest

Comment: The same is working fine for us

Comment: did you got answer for this